# I get WinError 32 and Errno 13 when trying to move a file with shutil.move

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to make a scripts that moves a file to a destination folder when it is added to the source folder but I get an error saying that the file I am trying to move is being used by something else.
The odd thing though is that it sometimes work just fine and sometimes trows the following error:

`PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/Python/download_manager/test/20200728_184438000_iOS.MOV' -> 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/Python/download_manager/test2/20200728_184438000_iOS.MOV'`

and

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/Python/download_manager/test/20200728_184438000_iOS.MOV'`

Here's my code:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


import os 
import json 
import time
import shutil

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
            new_destination = folder_destination + "/" + filename
            print ('moving {} to {}'.format(src,new_destination))
            shutil.move(src, new_destination)


folder_to_track = "C:/Users/olivi/Desktop/Python/download_manager/test"
folder_destination = "C:/Users/olivi/Desktop/Python/download_manager/test2"
event_handler = Handler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

EDIT:

I made the following changes and it seems to work more reliably now (even though it still freaks out sometimes ...):

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


import os 
import json 
import time
import shutil
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="logs.txt", filemode='w', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)-15s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S')

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):        
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            while True:
                src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
                new_destination = folder_destination + "/" + filename
                try:
                    shutil.move(src, new_destination)
                    logging.info('moved {} to {}'.format(src, new_destination))
                except PermissionError:
                    continue
                break
            
                
folder_to_track = "C:/Users/olivi/Downloads"
folder_destination = "C:/Users/olivi/Desktop/Python/download_manager/test"
event_handler = Handler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()
logging.info('--Service Started--')

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
    logging.warning(KeyboardInterrupt)
observer.join()
```

Comment: Guess: the `observer` has the folder locked so any attempt to modify the contents fail. Try stopping the `observer` before moving, then restart it.

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe `os.listdir` has the file locked. Try reading the file names into a list first.

Comment: The only thing I don’t understand is why sometimes it works perfectly fine and sometimes doesn’t...

Comment: If `folder_to_track` and `folder_destination` are in the same filesystem, then `shutil.move` can use `os.rename`. This requires opening the `src` file with delete (rename) access, which apparently is not shared by currently open references to the file, resulting in `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (32). `shutil.move` falls back on copying and deleting the file. Copying requires opening with read access, which also is probably failing with a sharing violation, but `open`, unlike `os.rename`, raises an exception only for generic `EACCES` (13), losing the specific Windows error code (32).

Comment: It's probably a race condition, for which the simplest resolution is to retry a few times in a loop with an increasing timeout.

Comment: @ErykSun I made the following changes (see original question) and it seems to work better now

Comment: Only `shutil.move(src, new_destination)` should be in the `try` statement.